# Unit-Test Redux-powered Angular App

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux

I recently upgraded the angular packages of my angular app, which involved upgrading:

- all @angular/* packages from `4.0.0` => `4.4.5`
- the @angular-redux/store package from `6.1.0` => `6.5.7`

In angular `4.0.0` with NgRedux `6.1.0`, this used to work:

```
store = new NgRedux<IAppState>(null);
store.configureStore(reducerConfig, undefined);
// etc.
```

But apparently, they made the `NgRedux` class `abstract`. Therefore, my unit tests would fail with the following exception: `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'NgRedux'.`

I tried to fix my tests by using a custom mocked class as proposed on [Testing Redux - Testing Simple Actions](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/redux/simple-actions.html):

```
class MockRedux extends NgRedux<any> {
  constructor() {
    super(null);
  }
  dispatch = () => undefined;
}
```

However, this failed due not implementing all abstract members with errors like this:

`[ts] Non-abstract class 'MockRedux' does not implement inherited abstract member 'configureSubStore' from class 'NgRedux<any>'.`

So the question arises: how do I properly mock a redux store with NgRedux within my angular specs?

Comment: have a look at this [**medium blog**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/unit-testing-of-ngrx-store-in-angular-app-d0935c8d8d1b)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by replacing `NgRedux` with `RootStore`:

```
// without zone
let store = new NgRedux<IAppState>(null);

// with zone
let store = new RootStore<IAppState>(new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: true}));
```

This works because `RootStore` is [inheriting](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/src/components/root-store.ts)  from the abstract `NgRedux` class, as seen in their repo:

```
// store/src/components/root-store.ts
export class RootStore<RootState> extends NgRedux<RootState> {
  private _store: Store<RootState>;
  private _store$: BehaviorSubject<RootState>;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
    super();
    // etc.
  }
  //etc.
}
```